# What if I want to develop for iOS 8 in XCode 7.3

Tags: objective-c, deployment, ios8, ios9, xcode7

I want to make an app for iOS 8 Support.

My Current Configuration is:

> Deployment Target - 8.0
>
> Base SDK - 9

What if I use some method which introduced in iOS 9. But Not in iOS8.

Will my app Crash ? is their any solution for it?

Comment: Yes, and there's thousands of blog posts and articles about how to deal with this situation.  Look for `respondsToSelector` to get started.

Comment: Sure, your app will be scrashed. Not really a solution: if-else, or use the older sdk based.

Comment: @phuongle I have one more doubt...Suppose I Set my `Deployment Target to 8` and base target `9` . And if I use any ios9 method then will xcode will prompt me for warning Or I have to manually find ios9 methods

Comment: Could you please share which method you want to call in iOS 8?